# Reference of what metric can be placed on manifold?

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, riemannian-geometry, geometric-topology, curvature

I just read some conclusion that $T^2$ can't be placed metric with positive curvature at all points. I don't know why is so . And what book introduce about this ? I mean about what metric can be placed after given some manifold.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This follows from [Gauss-Bonnet Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem#Statement_of_the_theorem): If $f$ is the Gaussian curvature of a compact surface $S$ without boundary, then 
$$\int_S f=2\pi\chi(S)$$
where $\chi(S)$ is the Euler characteristics of $S$. In particular, if $S$ is $T^2$ the torus, we have $\chi(S)=\chi(T^2)=0$. Therefore, it is impossible for $f>0$ everywhere.

BTW, for higher dimensional torus $T^n$, it is proved that its Yamabe constant is zero (due to Schoen and Yau?), which shows that it cannot be equipped with metric with positive scalar curvature at every point.

Answer (score 7):

By the [Gauss–Bonnet theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Bonnet_theorem), the Euler characteristic of $T^2$ is given by $$\chi(T^2) = \frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{T^2} K dA$$
where $K$ is the curvature and $dA$ is the element area of $T^2$. If $K$ were everywhere positive, then this would be a positive number, for the same reason that the integral of a positive function is positive; but $\chi(T^2) = \chi(S^1) \cdot \chi(S^1)$ is zero. Thus $K$ cannot be everywhere positive (and in fact if it's positive somewhere then it has to be negative at some other position).